# links in bootstrap 3.0 navbar not woking in mobile browser

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have included bootstrap 3.0 version of bootstrap.js and bootstrap.css. The problem what I was facing is navbar works fine in desktop browser even though I resize the browser but hyperlinks in navbar are not working in mobile browser. I know that independent of bootstrap nav bar should work since it is provided with `anchor` tags. I am newbie to bootstrap I don't know where I am getting problem from.

Here is my HTML Code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html >
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>PCCCTSG</title>

    <link href="bootstrap3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <style>
    .dropdown-menu{
    background:#333;

    }
    .dropdown-menu li a{
    color:#fff;

    }
    .row{
    color:#FFF; 
    }
.table-hover{
    color:#FFF;
}
.table-hover tr:hover{
    color:#333;
}
</style>
<link href="css/index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body style="font-family:cambria">
<div class="container" >
    <div class="row">
    &nbsp;
    </div>

    <div class="row glow"  style="background:#333">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">   
        <div class="row row-centered">
         <img src="images/header-lg.jpg" width="1130" height="142" alt="header" style="padding-top:10px" id="img-head"/></div>      
        <div class="row">
        &nbsp;
        </div>
<div class="row row-centered" >
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                   <nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-inverse">
                        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                        <div class="navbar-header">
                         <button type="button" data-target="#navbarCollapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle">
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Collection of nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                        <div id="navbarCollapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                                <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                                <li><a href="call-for-papers.html">Call for Papers</a></li>
                                <li class="active"><a href="#">Registration</a></li>
                                <li><a href="Committee.html">Committee</a></li>
                                <li><a href="important-dates.html">Important Dates</a></li>
                                <li><a href="Sponsor.html">Sponsorship</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Program</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
                               <!-- <li class="dropdown">
                                    <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">Messages <b class="caret"></b></a>
                                    <ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <li><a href="#">Inbox</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Drafts</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Sent Items</a></li>
                                        <li class="divider"></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Trash</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>-->
                            </ul>

                        </div>
                    </nav>
                </div>
               <div class="row row-centered">
                    <div class="col-md-10 col-centered">
                    <h5>Online registration page will be open soon. Please keep visiting the site for more updates.</h5>
                    <h4>The Registration fee is:</h4>
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                      <table width="686" class="table table-hover">
                        <tr>
                          <th width="219" scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
                          <th colspan="2" scope="col">Professionals</th>
                          <th colspan="2" scope="col">Students</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <th scope="row">&nbsp;</th>
                          <th width="104" scope="col">IEEE</th>
                          <th width="104" scope="col">Non-IEEE</th>
                          <th width="113" scope="col">IEEE </th>
                          <th width="112">Non-IEEE</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <th scope="row"><p>For Indian Delegates</p>
(In Indian Rupees)</th>
                          <td>6000</td>
                          <td>7000</td>
                          <td>3000</td>
                          <td>3750</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <th scope="row"><p>For Foreign Delegates</p>
(In US Dollars)</th>
                          <td>250</td>
                          <td>300</td>
                          <td>150</td>
                          <td>200</td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
                    </div>
                    </div>
               </div>
                <div class="col-md-11 col-sm-11 col-centered" >
                    &nbsp;

                 </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row row-centered">
          <div class="col-md-12 col-centered">
           <span style="float:right;color:#fff">
        Powered by Tarragon
        </span>
        </div>
          </div>    
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <p style="float:right;color:#fff">&nbsp;


        </p>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap3/js/bootstrap.min.js">
</script><script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an incorrect id in your collapse:

`id="navbarCollapse"` should be `navigationbar`.

The `data-target` cannot find your collapse as it's looking for `navigationbar` but your id is `navbarCollapse`. Remember if you are using data-target it must be the same as the ID. You need to read the [Documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar) more man:

Here it is in working order: [Bootply Example](http://www.bootply.com/zxEaDStEl1)

Comment: Actually I have tried with navbarCollapse it was not working so I written it as navigationbar. I am posting entire page code again please help me with that